# how to embed multiple plots to an HTML file and assign to a variable fig = bokeh.embed.file_html(p, bokeh.resources.CDN, '')

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm having an issue with creating a column layout in an HTML format.

My desired outcome is 2 plots stacked on top of each other.

here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```py
p1 = figure(width=600, height=300, title="Years vs mpg without jittering")
p1.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p1.xaxis.ticker = years
p1.scatter(x='yr', y='mpg', size=9, alpha=0.4, source=autompg)

p2 = figure(width=600, height=300, title="Years vs mpg with jittering")
p2.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p2.xaxis.ticker = years
p2.scatter(x=jitter('yr', 0.4), y='mpg', size=9, alpha=0.4, source=autompg)

fig = bokeh.embed.file_html([p1,p2] bokeh.resources.CDN, '')
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to accomplish. `file_html` returns a string containing HTML, that's all it will ever do. Are you trying to do something else? What does "assign to a variable" mean (what are you expecting to be able to assign, exactly)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a mistake in the last part of the code. is should look like this:                     fig = bokeh.embed.file_html(column(p1, p2), bokeh.resources.CDN, '')                                                
                                                                                                                                   I'm trying to save my 2 figures (in a column format) as an HTML file which will then be uploaded to a UI.